# Cast iron as EMF shield

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I wanted to ask if cast iron can be used as make-shift Electric and magnetic fields (EMF) shield.
For instance, can a frying-pan made of high-quality cast-iron and enamel be used as make-shift protection against laptop EMF?

I tried googling and found materials such as zinc, nickel, copper, steel. But none mentioned iron or cast-iron specifically.

Thanks.

Comment: You do know that steel is mostly iron?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  -yes I know but I haven't found iron itself specifically mentioned as type of EMF shield.

Comment: I don't know why the down-vote, care to explain?

Comment: Severe lack of  research or analysis done before asking

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I don't know what are you basing your statements on. I am not a physicist, I am a software developer, as such I have no adequate in-depth knowledge of physics nor do I have understanding of more complicated sources. All I can do is google for these things which I have done, and I can post links to Wikipedia articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key to effective shielding is complete coverage with no gaps or holes, using a good electrical conductor. For a cast-iron pan, complete coverage would require putting a close-fitting lid on top of the pan, which would cut off all your wi-fi & bluetooth connections and make the computer impossible to use.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks.